# Image upload previewing not working and form submits only after second click, in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, submit

I've created a simple form to upload pictures.

It allows the previewing of the image instantly after being chosen.

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE, where:
- the image preview doesn't work at all;
- the form gets submited successfuly only after the second (submit) button click.

Any ideas how to fix it?

You can see it happening at http://jsfiddle.net/renatogil/qFjrE/

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//PT" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!-- Include The jQuery Library -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
//----------------------------------------------------
// img preview
//----------------------------------------------------
//
function readURL(input, pic) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + pic)
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(120)
                .height(120);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <img id="product_pic" src="img/default_product_pic.jpg" width="120"
            height="120" alt="Click to upload..." /><input id="product"
            name="product" type="file"
            style="visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; display: none;"
            onchange="readURL(this, 'product_pic');"><br> <br> <input
            id="add_pic" type="button" value="Add picture">
        </div>

        <script>$('#product_pic').click(function() { $('#product').click(); });$('#add_pic').click(function() { $('#product').click(); });</script>

        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE<10 doesn't support html5 fileapi

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you're absolutely correct. I've updated to IE 10 and the preview now works. The submit issue remains. I believe it's because of the hidden input field. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a clising  after inspecting your code it does not open up anywhere?